# Why do I get an ErrorClosed when delaying HTTP requests in Windows?

Tags: http, haskell

I'm trying to implement the following pattern in a program that interfaces with the DGS website using the [HTTP library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP):

1. log in
2. get some data
3. let the user muck with the data
4. send the modified data back
5. start again at step two

It works great on Linux, but from Windows, the program prints `Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorClosed` at step four. I've distilled the above pattern into a minimal test case below:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Network.Browser
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI

auth = URIAuth
    { uriRegName = "dragongoserver.sourceforge.net"
    , uriUserInfo = ""
    , uriPort = ""
    }

uri path = nullURI
    { uriScheme = "http:"
    , uriAuthority = Just auth
    , uriPath = '/' : path
    }

get path = request . formToRequest . Form GET (uri path)

main = browse $ do
    get "login.php" [("quick_mode", "1"), ("userid", "smartypants"), ("passwd", "smartypants")]
    ioAction (threadDelay 5000000)
    get "sgf.php" [("gid", "491179")]
```

How can I keep the connection open?

Comment: Have you tried adding `withSocketsDo` from Network.Socket package? Doc states: "On Windows operating systems, the networking subsystem has to be initialised using withSocketsDo before any networking operations can be used." - and at least I can't see Network.TCP or Network.HTTP doing it.

Comment: `withSocketsDo` doesn't seem to change anything, but I have since discovered that the question is ill-formed: the problem occurs on Linux, as well. I'll track down the difference between the program that works and the one that doesn't, and make a better question. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @AndrewC Nope. I've since switched libraries, though I don't know yet whether the other library has an analogous problem or not (the program is both in the middle of a fairly major overhaul and sort of on the backburner for me, a combination that doesn't result in a lot of fast progress).